# Mongo Db bulk update operation for data type conversion

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to perform bulk operation for mongo db? I already have script to change data type but it is not considering huge volume.

Collection 'store' has column called 'priceList' which is Array having multiple fields one of which is 'value'. Right now it is integer and now I want to convert it to custom record object.

**Current schema**

```
store
 - _id  
 - name [String]
 - priceList [Array]
    - amount [Record] //{"unscaled":<value>, "scaled", <value>}
    - value  [Integer]
```

Need to convert value to [Record] as mentioned in above format
For e.g:- value: 2 will become value: {"unscaled":2, "scaled", 0};

```
db.store.find({priceList: { $exists : true}}).forEach(function(obj){
   obj.priceList.forEach(function(y){
       y.value = ({"unscaled":NumberLong(y.value),"scaled",NumberInt(0)});
       db.store.save(obj);
   })          
});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try like this,

```
db.store.find({
    priceList: {
        $exists: true
    }
}).forEach(function(myDoc) {
    var child = myDoc.priceList;
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        var ob = child[i];
        var obj = {"unscaled":NumberLong(ob.value),"scaled":NumberInt(0)};
        if ('value' in ob) {
            ob.value = obj;
            child[i] = ob;
        }

    }
    db.store.update({
        _id: myDoc._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            subMenu: child
        }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps (updated) !

```
db.store.find({priceList: {$exists: true}})
.toArray()
.forEach(o => db.store.update(
{_id: o._id},
{ $set: {
  priceList: o.priceList.map(l => Object.assign(l, {
    amount: {
    unscaled: l.value,
    scaled: 0
    }
  }))
 }
}
))
```

Comment: I don't want to change entire priceList array just one field called value under priceList.